# How to check Before and After Date Times in Java for dates that are UTC in MySQL but for Multiple Time Zones?

Tags: java, mysql, date, datetime, utc

Have a table setup in MySQL that holds data for an event (e.g. a music show or karaoke) at a particular place of business.

So my table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `event_schedule` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT,
  `event_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_date_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
)
```

Database table contains rows like this:

```
| 1 | karoake | aab3223  | 2017-08-15 00:00:00 | 2017-08-15 16:00:00 |
| 2 | comedy  | cce8465  | 2017-08-25 00:00:00 | 2017-08-25 19:00:00 |
```

The event_date is in UTC Time format as well is the MySQL server that it resides in.

```
select now()
```

Will give time in UTC...

Have logic setup which uses a Spring JDBC to check if a particular row exists based on curdate() like this:

```
@Repository
public class EventDao {

    private static JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = null;

    @Autowired
    public EventDao(@Qualifier("aDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        EventDao.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public static String getEventId() {
        SqlRowSet eventRowSet = null;
        String eventId = "";
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        dateInUTC = formatter.format(new Date());

        eventRowSet = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(
            "select * from event_schedule where (event_date=CURDATE() or event_date=?)",
            new Object[] { dateInUTC });

        if (eventRowSet != null && eventRowSet.next()) {
            eventId = rst.getString("event_id");
        }
        return eventId;
    }
}
```

A class used to check if the event is under way:

```
 public class EventProcessor {

    public static String getEventStatus() {
        String eventId = getEventId();
        if (eventId != null) {
            return "Event Started";
        }
        else {
            return "Event not Started"
        }
        // TODO: Need to incorporate for two hours after its over.
        // "Event Ended"
    }
 }
```

This system seemed to be working when the requirements dependent on just the event_date in UTC was simply:

```
2017-08-15 00:00:00
```

New Use Case(s) / Question(s):

If a client app connects to this web service and the situation is:

event starts 2017-08-15 19:00:00 (lets say this is 7:00 p.m PST) how can I set it up do this:

1. Have the service return "Event Not Started" from 2017-08-14 00:00 to 2017-08-15 18:59:59 ?

Meaning, from the midnight of the same date until one minute before it starts?

---

2. Have the service return "Event Ended" two hours after the event ends?

---

A lot of my client apps that connect to this web service might be in the West Coast (PST), Central (CST), or Eastern (EST).

3. What is the best way to do a time conversion for them (since I am using UTC Datetimes in the MySQL Database and the MySQL Database is in UTC itself)?

Answer (score 0):

This has been addressed many times already from different angles on Stack Overflow. So search for more info.

Briefly…

I don't use Spring, so here is the basic JDBC to guide you.

Use only java.time classes. Avoid the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `Date`, `Calendar`, and the `java.sql` classes.

Store your date-times in UTC if they are past moments in history, or specific moments coming up soon. Query in UTC. Present in user’s expected time zone.

If scheduling more that several weeks out, you may want to use a date-time value without a zone or offset, as politicians frequently re-define time zones with little advance notice. I'll ignore that here.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `PST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```java
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of( 2017 , 8 , 15 ) ;
LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.of( 19 , 0 ) ;
ZonedDateTime start = ZonedDateTime.of( startDate , startTime , z ) ;
Duration d = Duration.ofHours( 2 ) ;
ZonedDateTime stop = start.plus( d ) ;
```

If you want to store the `Duration`, call `toString` and store its generated String using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format.

### Half-Open logic

Use Half-Open logic, where **beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive***. This entirely avoids your mess with “from the midnight of the same date until one minute before it starts?”.

```java
String sql = "INSERT INTO event ( start , stop , duration , … ) VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ...) ;" ;
… make prepared statement
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , start.toInstant() ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 2 , stop.toInstant() ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 3 , duration.toString() ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , … ) ;
```

Query is similar.

```java
String sql = "SELECT start , stop , duration , pkey , …  FROM event WHERE pkey = ? ;" ) ; 
… execute query, get ResultSet
… loop the resulting rows
Instant start = myResultSet.get( 1 , Instant.class ) ; 
Instant stop = myResultSet.get( 2 , Instant.class ) ;
Duration d = Duration.parse( myResultSet.getString( 3 ) ) ;
```

Compare to the current moment.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
Boolean eventScheduled = now.isBefore( start ) ;
Boolean eventOccurring = ( ! now.isBefore( start ) ) && now.isBefore( stop ) ;
Boolean eventExpired = ! now.isBefore( stop ) ;  // "Not before stop" means either (a ) now is exactly the moment of expiration (using half-open logic we consider that past), or (b) now is later, after the moment of expiration.
```

If you want to query for events not yet started:

```
String sql = "SELECT start , stop , duration , pkey , …  FROM event WHERE start > ? ; " ) ; // Find events starting after the passed moment.
…
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , Instant.now() ) ;
```

The above code assumes your JDBC driver complies with JDBC 4.2 or later for supporting java.time types directly.